# Ionic 3 ion-label on ion-range being truncated

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to put an ion-label that has the text $$$$$ on it for a price range. The range is inside an ion-menu. Here is the code I have:

```
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Price Range</ion-label>
            <ion-range min="1" max="5" snaps="true" dualKnobs="true" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="priceRange" color="primary">
                <ion-label range-left>$</ion-label>
                <ion-label range-right>$$$$$</ion-label>
            </ion-range>
        </ion-item>
```

Which oddly displays this:

[image]

Even though I have $$$$$ in the html, it only displays $$.

For some reason, if I type in multiple extra $'s the display changes. For example:

```
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Price Range</ion-label>
            <ion-range min="1" max="5" snaps="true" dualKnobs="true" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="priceRange" color="primary">
                <ion-label range-left>$</ion-label>
                <ion-label range-right>$$$$$$$$$$</ion-label>
            </ion-range>
        </ion-item>
```

Displays this:

[image]

Although this is the desired display I would like, it doesn't seem right to have to do what I did to achieve that.

How can I get the label to display $$$$$ in the proper way? I have tried setting the width, padding, and border properties to try and give the label more space but it does not affect anything.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way. Declare any variable in your component file like below,

```
symbol : any = '$$$$$';
```

and then you can use it like below,

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Price Range</ion-label>
<ion-range min="1" max="5" snaps="true" dualKnobs="true" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="priceRange" color="primary">
<ion-label range-left>$</ion-label>
<ion-label range-right>{{symbol}}</ion-label>
</ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, no idea why this works and my original attempt doesn't though haha.